# Change or rearrange Magento Login and Log Out (top links) position using local.xml

Tags: xml, magento, hyperlink

I'd like to rearrange my top links using `local.xml`--specifically the login/log out links. Is this possible without removing the links then re-adding them and modifying their position tags?

Currently (and by default) Log In and Log Out are set to position 100 in `customer.xml`:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log Out</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            <title>Log Out</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log In</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
            <title>Log In</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

I would like them both at position 1 (via `local.xml`).

I am aware of the `setAttribute` action method but I am unsure how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found a more efficient way to do this within `local.xml`, so I have removed the links and re-added them with modified position parameters:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log Out</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            <title>Log Out</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>4</position>
            <liParams>id="top-logout"</liParams>
            <aParams/>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log In</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
            <title>Log In</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>4</position>
            <liParams>id="top-login"</liParams>
            <aParams/>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `top.links` block's `addLink` method is used to add links to this block. When you look at that method's body you will see that position parameter is used to determine the position of links.

The link position is determined by this chunk of code:

```
 $this->_links[$this->_getNewPosition($position)] = $link;
 if (intval($position) > 0) {
     ksort($this->_links);
 }
```

`_getNewPosition()` method checks if that particular position is still available. If it is not, then it will search for closest available one (i.e., at position 1 there can be only one link). After the link's correct position is retrieved, the whole array of links is sorted.

In your case, the position of both login and logout links is set by default to 100 (see the `<position />` tag). So, you should copy the layout xml (`customer.xml`) into your theme's layout directory and change the position parameters to 1.

If those links won't render at position 1, it means that some other link had its position set to 1 before yours. In such case, just change position of that link to a greater number. Please note that you cannot use position values less than or equal to zero.

Comment: I am aware of `getNewPosition()` and I am aware that I can copy the xml file to my theme's layout directory. However, as stated in my original question, I would like to modify the links' positions via `local.xml` in an effort to maintain my layout changes in a central location. The only way I've figured to do this so far is to remove the links in `local.xml` and then add them back immediately and setting the position parameter on re-add. These links both have different handles which should not cause position conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the position number of Top Links.

based on these you can set or change the position of top links

```
My Account = 10 
Whislist = 30 
Mycart = 50 
Checkout = 60
Login/Logout = 100
```